# Birthday paradox for years with $D$ days, with $D$ large

Tags: combinatorics, limits

I just learned about the birthday paradox and was quite fascinated that you only need 23 people to have a 50% probability that two people share the same birthday.
this is 365.

The chance p = 1 - 365!/(365^n * (365-n)!), with n the number of people.

My question: if there would be more days in a year than 365, how many people would you need to have a 50% probability that two share the same birthday. Specifically:

> If there are D days in a year, when D approaches infinity, how many people would you need (expressed in D)?

I have the feeling it the answer contains Euler constant for some reason.

Comment: $$n(D)\sim\sqrt{2(\ln 2)D}$$

Comment: When D approaches infinity, you would need an infinite number of people in order to have a $50\%$ probability that two people share the same birthday.